# Why my array is posted as comma delimited string?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following scenario

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
         CheckBoxes();
         Post();
 });
```

with

```
function CheckBoxes()
{
    var manData = new Array();

    $('input:checked').each(function ()
    {
        if(this.name === 'man') manData.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('#man').val(manData);
}
```

and

```
function Post()
 {

     var postData = {
     'man': $('#man').val()
                };

                var path = "/Home/Index";
                $.ajax({
                    url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
                    dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify(postData)
                }).success(function (response) {

                }).error(function (){

                });
            }
```

which results in posting data as

`{"man":"2,3"}` and not as an array

```
{"man": ["2,3"]}.
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
$('#man').val(manData);
```

It's converting your array into a comma separated string. So when you get it back, split it again:

```
var postData = {
    'man': $('#man').val().split(",")
};
```